# Run time error '1004' AutoFilter of method range class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter column M (aka field 13) to 0 values so I can delete them, but keep getting the error autofilter method of Range class failed.

```
Range("M2").Formula = "=IF(K2<4,1,0)"
Range("M2").Copy
Range("M2:M" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Range("M:M").Copy
Range("M:M").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Range("K:M").NumberFormat = "##,##0"

Cells.AutoFilter _
    field:=13, _
    Criteria1:=0
```

This macro worked without fail since it was written (a couple years) and just in the last couple weeks it would stop at this error. The source code has not been touched so not sure why it would stop working. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sure nobody removed the filters from the header?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I am certain that no one messed with the filters.